# Group-by date, given a varchar (string)

Tags: mysql, sql, date, group-by

I am given a database with a table that contains the attribute "datum" (varchar(25)). Because of poor database design, this column is filled with date values in string format, for example:

> 'February 25, 2013, 3:47 p'

I need to query the table and group all rows by day (so 25 in the example above).
Should I be using the DATE_FORMAT(datum, '') function to be able to do this? Whenever I use that function, I get null values.

Comment: It would help if you told us what format string you passed as a parameter

Comment: I used DATE_FORMAT(datum, '%M %e, %Y, %h:%i %p')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is a string, you should convert it to a valid date value using `STR_TO_DATE`

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tableName
WHERE   STR_TO_DATE(datum,'%M %e, %Y, %h:%i %p') ....
```

The difference between the two:

STR_TO_DATE - converts string to date 
DATE_FORMAT - converts date to string

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `STR_TO_DATE()` function ([documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date))?

It is the inverse of `DATE_FORMAT()` which takes a date value as its first parameter, not a string. You can then use that to get the correct day values.

Here is an SQL command that matches your query, I tested and works.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT( STR_TO_DATE(datum,'%M %e, %Y, %h:%i %p'), '%d' ) = 25;
```

Comment: I'm trying out the example below, using STR_TO_DATE(). Thanks!